# What is the proper naming convention for a web service in .NET?

Tags: .net, web-services

I'm creating a webservice, and I want to name it appropriately.

Right now my service is named Service as per the /App_Code/Service.cs

Should I rename it to something like: *com.example.MyWebService.cs*?

How do I get around the class file not excepting '.' in the file name?

Answer (score 4):

the "com.example.whatever" namespace thing is java specific.  Microsoft recommends that you use Company.Product.etc..

Check out the Naming guidelines at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Answer (score 0):

com.example would be the namespace, and not part of the class/service name.

You should do:

```
namespace Com.Example
{
    public class MyWebService
    {
        // class contents
    }
}
```